# How to change the npm version for single project in vscode?

Tags: npm

My current npm version is 6.14.13 and I need 6.14.14 version.

I tried "npm i npm@6.14.14".. Where to put this command?

Comment: Typically, "npm" is installed - and updated - globally.  Just run `npm -g npm` from a command prompt to upgrade from your current version to the latest/greatest version.

Answer (score 0):

install nvm (node version manager). and change node/npm version in terminal.

```
nvm use 14.18.0
// this will change node version in currently open terminal tab
```